# abort: invalid certificate using Mercurial and TortoiseHG and bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am receiving an error when pushing changessets to my repositories:

When I push to bitbucket.org I get:

```
abort: invalid certificate for `bitbucket.org` with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b
```

When I push to RepositoryHosting.com I get:

```
abort: invalid certificate for `sfi.repositoryhosting.com` with fingerprint d1:a6:19:f6:04:33:e6:6f:dc:bb:f1:83:72:fc:ba:2a:b6:b7:a3:e5
```

When I push to a third site (`trunksapp.com`) I do not get the error.  I am using HTTPS for all three hosting sites.

The failure occurs in the command line and in TortoiseHG both.
I have a script that does several pushes.  All pushed are failing for the hosting sites that are failing.  They did work at one time.  All scripts are succeeding for the site that does not get the certificate error.  The script has not been modified in a long time.

The scripts are scheduled to run every night.  I do not know how long they have been failing.

I did try the `--insecure` option.  It made no difference.

Thank you in advance for your help
Jim

Comment: did you tried --verbose option or|and --debug? I see `CN = *.repositoryhosting.com`, it may be problem, "bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified" in case of -v --debug from my side and vanilla TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\cacert.pem exist

Comment: Did you specify a (possibly wrong) fingerprint for Bitbucket in your hgrc file [hostfingerprints] section?

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely related to upgrading Mercurial to 1.7.  See the following page: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates.  Mercurial has just gotten stricter and is making you configure your CA certificates.